# Displaying multiple routes using Directions API in Android

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2, directions

I am using this class to display a route on a map. The problem is that it only displays one route. What I want to do is display multiple alternate routes on the map. Even thought the server response has multiple routes, it only parses the first route and displays it. What changes should I make to display all the routes that the google server returns.Here is my class.

```
public class GMapV2Direction {
    public final static String MODE_DRIVING = "driving";
    public final static String MODE = "walking";
    public final static String MODE_WALKING = "walking";

    public GMapV2Direction() { }

    public Document getDocument(LatLng start, LatLng end, String mode) {
        String url = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/xml?" 
                + "origin=" + start.latitude + "," + start.longitude  
                + "&destination=" + end.latitude + "," + end.longitude 
                + "&sensor=false&units=metric&mode="+MODE+"alternatives=true";

        try {
            HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpContext localContext = new BasicHttpContext();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
            HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost, localContext);
            InputStream in = response.getEntity().getContent();
            DocumentBuilder builder = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder();
            Document doc = builder.parse(in);
            return doc;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    public String getDurationText (Document doc) {
        NodeList nl1 = doc.getElementsByTagName("duration");
        Node node1 = nl1.item(0);
        NodeList nl2 = node1.getChildNodes();
        Node node2 = nl2.item(getNodeIndex(nl2, "text"));
        Log.i("DurationText", node2.getTextContent());
        return node2.getTextContent();
    }

    public int getDurationValue (Document doc) {

        NodeList nl1 = doc.getElementsByTagName("duration");
        Node node1 = nl1.item(0);
        NodeList nl2 = node1.getChildNodes();
        Node node2 = nl2.item(getNodeIndex(nl2, "value"));
        Log.i("DurationValue", node2.getTextContent());
        return Integer.parseInt(node2.getTextContent());

    }

    public String getDistanceText (Document doc) {
        NodeList nl1 = doc.getElementsByTagName("distance");
        Node node1 = nl1.item(0);
        NodeList nl2 = node1.getChildNodes();
        Node node2 = nl2.item(getNodeIndex(nl2, "text"));
        Log.i("DistanceText", node2.getTextContent());
        return node2.getTextContent();
    }

    public int getDistanceValue (Document doc) {
        NodeList nl1 = doc.getElementsByTagName("distance");
        Node node1 = nl1.item(0);
        NodeList nl2 = node1.getChildNodes();
        Node node2 = nl2.item(getNodeIndex(nl2, "value"));
        Log.i("DistanceValue", node2.getTextContent());
        return Integer.parseInt(node2.getTextContent());
    }

    public String getStartAddress (Document doc) {
        NodeList nl1 = doc.getElementsByTagName("start_address");
        Node node1 = nl1.item(0);
        Log.i("StartAddress", node1.getTextContent());
        return node1.getTextContent();
    }

    public String getEndAddress (Document doc) {
        NodeList nl1 = doc.getElementsByTagName("end_address");
        Node node1 = nl1.item(0);
        Log.i("EndAddress", node1.getTextContent());
        return node1.getTextContent();
    }

    public String getCopyRights (Document doc) {
        NodeList nl1 = doc.getElementsByTagName("copyrights");
        Node node1 = nl1.item(0);
        Log.i("CopyRights", node1.getTextContent());
        return node1.getTextContent();
    }

    public ArrayList<LatLng> getDirection (Document doc) {
        NodeList nl1, nl2, nl3;
        ArrayList<LatLng> listGeopoints = new ArrayList<LatLng>();
        nl1 = doc.getElementsByTagName("step");
        if (nl1.getLength() > 0) {
            for (int i = 0; i < nl1.getLength(); i++) {
                Node node1 = nl1.item(i);
                nl2 = node1.getChildNodes();

                Node locationNode = nl2.item(getNodeIndex(nl2, "start_location"));
                nl3 = locationNode.getChildNodes();
                Node latNode = nl3.item(getNodeIndex(nl3, "lat"));
                double lat = Double.parseDouble(latNode.getTextContent());
                Node lngNode = nl3.item(getNodeIndex(nl3, "lng"));
                double lng = Double.parseDouble(lngNode.getTextContent());
                listGeopoints.add(new LatLng(lat, lng));

                locationNode = nl2.item(getNodeIndex(nl2, "polyline"));
                nl3 = locationNode.getChildNodes();
                latNode = nl3.item(getNodeIndex(nl3, "points"));
                ArrayList<LatLng> arr = decodePoly(latNode.getTextContent());
                for(int j = 0 ; j < arr.size() ; j++) {
                    listGeopoints.add(new LatLng(arr.get(j).latitude, arr.get(j).longitude));
                }

                locationNode = nl2.item(getNodeIndex(nl2, "end_location"));
                nl3 = locationNode.getChildNodes();
                latNode = nl3.item(getNodeIndex(nl3, "lat"));
                lat = Double.parseDouble(latNode.getTextContent());
                lngNode = nl3.item(getNodeIndex(nl3, "lng"));
                lng = Double.parseDouble(lngNode.getTextContent());
                listGeopoints.add(new LatLng(lat, lng));
            }
        }

        return listGeopoints;
    }

    private int getNodeIndex(NodeList nl, String nodename) {
        for(int i = 0 ; i < nl.getLength() ; i++) {
            if(nl.item(i).getNodeName().equals(nodename))
                return i;
        }
        return -1;
    }

    private ArrayList<LatLng> decodePoly(String encoded) {
        ArrayList<LatLng> poly = new ArrayList<LatLng>();
        int index = 0, len = encoded.length();
        int lat = 0, lng = 0;
        while (index < len) {
            int b, shift = 0, result = 0;
            do {
                b = encoded.charAt(index++) - 63;
                result |= (b & 0x1f) << shift;
                shift += 5;
            } while (b >= 0x20);
            int dlat = ((result & 1) != 0 ? ~(result >> 1) : (result >> 1));
            lat += dlat;
            shift = 0;
            result = 0;
            do {
                b = encoded.charAt(index++) - 63;
                result |= (b & 0x1f) << shift;
                shift += 5;
            } while (b >= 0x20);
            int dlng = ((result & 1) != 0 ? ~(result >> 1) : (result >> 1));
            lng += dlng;

            LatLng position = new LatLng((double) lat / 1E5, (double) lng / 1E5);
            poly.add(position);
        }
        return poly;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

i think you don't have to get the response of *Google Server* and parse it in **Document**, other wise you can convert from **InputStream** to **String** using:

```
private String convertStreamToString(final InputStream input) throws Exception {
    try {
        final BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(input));
        final StringBuffer sBuf = new StringBuffer();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sBuf.append(line);
        }
        return sBuf.toString();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw e;
    } finally {
        try {
            input.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw e;
        }
    }
```

then you will have to parse the response as JSONObject

```
JSONObject jSONObject = new JSONObject(string);
```

then you get **JSONArray** named *routes*

```
JSONArray routeJSONArray = jSONObject.getJSONArray("routes");
```

now you can start fetching data from each route by getting its index from JSONArray.

i have written a snippet of code as a model of route

**Route.java**

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import android.content.Context;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Polyline;

public class Route implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private Bound bounds;
    private String copyrights;
    private List<Leg> legs;
    private Polyline overviewPolyLine;
    private String summary;

    public Route(Context context) {
        legs = new ArrayList<Leg>();
    }

    public Bound getBounds() {
        return bounds;
    }

    public void setBounds(Bound bounds) {
        this.bounds = bounds;
    }

    public String getCopyrights() {
        return copyrights;
    }

    public void setCopyrights(String copyrights) {
        this.copyrights = copyrights;
    }

    public List<Leg> getLegs() {
        return legs;
    }

    public void setLegs(List<Leg> legs) {
        this.legs = legs;
    }

    public void addLeg(Leg leg) {
        this.legs.add(leg);
    }

    public Polyline getOverviewPolyLine() {
        return overviewPolyLine;
    }

    public void setOverviewPolyLine(Polyline overviewPolyLine) {
        this.overviewPolyLine = overviewPolyLine;
    }

    public String getSummary() {
        return summary;
    }

    public void setSummary(String summary) {
        this.summary = summary;
    }

    public static long getSerialversionuid() {
        return serialVersionUID;
    }

}
```

**Bound.java**

```
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;

public class Bound {
    private LatLng northEast;
    private LatLng southWest;
    public LatLng getNorthEast() {
        return northEast;
    }
    public void setNorthEast(LatLng northEast) {
        this.northEast = northEast;
    }
    public LatLng getSouthWest() {
        return southWest;
    }
    public void setSouthWest(LatLng southWest) {
        this.southWest = southWest;
    }
}
```

**Leg.java**

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;

public class Leg {
    private Distance distance;
    private Duration duration;
    private String endAddress;
    private LatLng endLocation;
    private String startAddress;
    private LatLng startLocation;
    private List<Step> steps;

    public Leg() {
        steps = new ArrayList<Step>();
    }

    public Distance getDistance() {
        return distance;
    }

    public void setDistance(Distance distance) {
        this.distance = distance;
    }

    public Duration getDuration() {
        return duration;
    }

    public void setDuration(Duration duration) {
        this.duration = duration;
    }

    public String getEndAddress() {
        return endAddress;
    }

    public void setEndAddress(String endAddress) {
        this.endAddress = endAddress;
    }

    public LatLng getEndLocation() {
        return endLocation;
    }

    public void setEndLocation(LatLng endLocation) {
        this.endLocation = endLocation;
    }

    public String getStartAddress() {
        return startAddress;
    }

    public void setStartAddress(String startAddress) {
        this.startAddress = startAddress;
    }

    public LatLng getStartLocation() {
        return startLocation;
    }

    public void setStartLocation(LatLng startLocation) {
        this.startLocation = startLocation;
    }

    public List<Step> getSteps() {
        return steps;
    }

    public void setSteps(List<Step> steps) {
        this.steps = steps;
    }

    public void addStep(Step step) {
        this.steps.add(step);
    }

}
```

**Distance.java**

```
public class Distance {
    private String text;
    private long value;

    public Distance(String text, long value) {
        this.text = text;
        this.value = value;
    }

    public String getText() {
        return text;
    }

    public void setText(String text) {
        this.text = text;
    }

    public long getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(long value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

}
```

**Duration.java**

```
public class Duration {
    public Duration(String text, long value) {
        this.text = text;
        this.value = value;
    }

    private String text;
    private long value;

    public String getText() {
        return text;
    }

    public void setText(String text) {
        this.text = text;
    }

    public long getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(long value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

}
```

**Step.java**

```
import java.util.List;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.nweave.etaxi.driver.R;

public class Step {
    private Distance distance;
    private Duration duration;
    private LatLng endLocation;
    private LatLng startLocation;
    private String htmlInstructions;
    private String travelMode;
    private List<LatLng> points;

    public List<LatLng> getPoints() {
        return points;
    }

    public void setPoints(List<LatLng> points) {
        this.points = points;
    }

    public Distance getDistance() {
        return distance;
    }

    public void setDistance(Distance distance) {
        this.distance = distance;
    }

    public Duration getDuration() {
        return duration;
    }

    public void setDuration(Duration duration) {
        this.duration = duration;
    }

    public LatLng getEndLocation() {
        return endLocation;
    }

    public void setEndLocation(LatLng endLocation) {
        this.endLocation = endLocation;
    }

    public LatLng getStartLocation() {
        return startLocation;
    }

    public void setStartLocation(LatLng startLocation) {
        this.startLocation = startLocation;
    }

    public String getHtmlInstructions() {
        return htmlInstructions;
    }

    public void setHtmlInstructions(String htmlInstructions) {
        this.htmlInstructions = htmlInstructions;
    }

    public String getTravelMode() {
        return travelMode;
    }

    public void setTravelMode(String travelMode) {
        this.travelMode = travelMode;
    }
}
```

the parsing function will be

```
public List<Route> parse(String routesJSONString) throws Exception {
    try {
        List<Route> routeList = new ArrayList<Route>();
        final JSONObject jSONObject = new JSONObject(routesJSONString);
        JSONArray routeJSONArray = jSONObject.getJSONArray(ROUTES);
        Route route;
        JSONObject routesJSONObject;
        for (int m = 0; m < routeJSONArray.length(); m++) {
            route = new Route(context);
            routesJSONObject = routeJSONArray.getJSONObject(m);
            JSONArray legsJSONArray;
            route.setSummary(routesJSONObject.getString(SUMMARY));
            legsJSONArray = routesJSONObject.getJSONArray(LEGS);
            JSONObject legJSONObject;
            Leg leg;
            JSONArray stepsJSONArray;
            for (int b = 0; b < legsJSONArray.length(); b++) {
                leg = new Leg();
                legJSONObject = legsJSONArray.getJSONObject(b);
                leg.setDistance(new Distance(legJSONObject.optJSONObject(DISTANCE).optString(TEXT), legJSONObject.optJSONObject(DISTANCE).optLong(VALUE)));
                leg.setDuration(new Duration(legJSONObject.optJSONObject(DURATION).optString(TEXT), legJSONObject.optJSONObject(DURATION).optLong(VALUE)));
                stepsJSONArray = legJSONObject.getJSONArray(STEPS);
                JSONObject stepJSONObject, stepDurationJSONObject, legPolyLineJSONObject, stepStartLocationJSONObject, stepEndLocationJSONObject;
                Step step;
                String encodedString;
                LatLng stepStartLocationLatLng, stepEndLocationLatLng;
                for (int i = 0; i < stepsJSONArray.length(); i++) {
                    stepJSONObject = stepsJSONArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    step = new Step();
                    JSONObject stepDistanceJSONObject = stepJSONObject.getJSONObject(DISTANCE);
                    step.setDistance(new Distance(stepDistanceJSONObject.getString(TEXT), stepDistanceJSONObject.getLong(VALUE)));
                    stepDurationJSONObject = stepJSONObject.getJSONObject(DURATION);
                    step.setDuration(new Duration(stepDurationJSONObject.getString(TEXT), stepDurationJSONObject.getLong(VALUE)));
                    stepEndLocationJSONObject = stepJSONObject.getJSONObject(END_LOCATION);
                    stepEndLocationLatLng = new LatLng(stepEndLocationJSONObject.getDouble(LATITUDE), stepEndLocationJSONObject.getDouble(LONGITUDE));
                    step.setEndLocation(stepEndLocationLatLng);
                    step.setHtmlInstructions(stepJSONObject.getString(HTML_INSTRUCTION));
                    legPolyLineJSONObject = stepJSONObject.getJSONObject(POLYLINE);
                    encodedString = legPolyLineJSONObject.getString(POINTS);
                    step.setPoints(decodePolyLines(encodedString));
                    stepStartLocationJSONObject = stepJSONObject.getJSONObject(START_LOCATION);
                    stepStartLocationLatLng = new LatLng(stepStartLocationJSONObject.getDouble(LATITUDE), stepStartLocationJSONObject.getDouble(LONGITUDE));
                    step.setStartLocation(stepStartLocationLatLng);
                    leg.addStep(step);
                }
                route.addLeg(leg);
            }
            routeList.add(route);
        }
        return routeList;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw e;
    }
```

Regarding the **Step Image** there is an HTML instruction and another field called **maneuver** where according to this field you will choose your image

i hope this helps ;)

Comment: You just saved my time :) I was actually going to write all those models and parse JSON step by step, thank you :)

Comment: @Ajji It's my pleasure

Comment: @3amoura: I have a confusion... ... Why have you used Serializable in Route.java ??

Comment: @R.K, No need to make it serializable, I just forgot to remove this, I wanted to pass Route from one Activity to another through Intent Extras. But Serializable here is not mandatory. Sorry for this confusion.

Comment: Ok... thanks.. for your answer... works well @3amoura

Comment: that's fine, but now how to show multiple direction/route in google map.

Comment: Here you got all the routes available, You are free to show all of them with different colors.

Comment: Can u send me snippet code for show all different route in google map??

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do something like this

```
LatLng origin = sourcePosition;
     LatLng dest = destPosition;

  DownloadTask1 downloadTask = new DownloadTask1();
  String url = downloadTask.getDirectionsUrl1(origin, dest);                   
  downloadTask.execute(url);
```

DownloadTask1 class

```
 private class DownloadTask1 extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

        // Downloading data in non-ui thread
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... url) {

            // For storing data from web service
            String data = "";

            try {
                // Fetching the data from web service
                data = downloadUrl(url[0]);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.d("Background Task", e.toString());
            }
            return data;
        }

        // Executes in UI thread, after the execution of
        // doInBackground()
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);

            ParserTask1 parserTask = new ParserTask1();

            // Invokes the thread for parsing the JSON data
            parserTask.execute(result);
        }


        private String getDirectionsUrl1(LatLng origin, LatLng dest) {

            // Origin of route
            String str_origin = "origin=" + origin.latitude + "," + origin.longitude;

            // Destination of route
            String str_dest = "destination=" + dest.latitude + "," + dest.longitude;

            // Sensor enabled
            String sensor = "sensor=false&alternatives=true&units=metric&mode=driving";
            //&alternatives=true&units=metric&mode=driving
            // Building the parameters to the web service
            String parameters = str_origin + "&" + str_dest + "&" + sensor;

            // Output format
            String output = "json";

            // Building the url to the web service
            String url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/" + output + "?" + parameters;

            return url;
        }
    }
```

downloadUrl() method

```
private String downloadUrl(String strUrl) throws IOException {
        String data = "";
        InputStream iStream = null;
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
        try{
            URL url = new URL(strUrl);

            // Creating an http connection to communicate with url
            urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

            // Connecting to url
            urlConnection.connect();

            // Reading data from url
            iStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();

            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(iStream));

            StringBuffer sb  = new StringBuffer();

            String line = "";
            while( ( line = br.readLine())  != null){
                sb.append(line);
            }

            data = sb.toString();

            br.close();

        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            //Log.d("Exception while downloading url", e.toString());
        }finally{
            iStream.close();
            urlConnection.disconnect();
        }
        return data;
    }
```

ParserTask1 class

```
private class ParserTask1 extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, List<List<List<HashMap<String, String>>>>> {

        // Parsing the data in non-ui thread
        @Override
        protected List<List<List<HashMap<String, String>>>> doInBackground(String... jsonData) {

            JSONObject jObject;
            List<List<List<HashMap<String, String>>>> routes = null;

            try {
                jObject = new JSONObject(jsonData[0]);
                DirectionsJSONParser parser = new DirectionsJSONParser();

                // Starts parsing data
                routes = parser.parse(jObject);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return routes;
        }

        // Executes in UI thread, after the parsing process
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(List<List<List<HashMap<String, String>>>> result) {
            ArrayList<LatLng> points = null;
            PolylineOptions lineOptions = new PolylineOptions();

            PolylineOptions lineOptions1 = null;
            MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
            String distance = "";
            String duration = "";

            Integer size1 = 0;
            Integer size2 = 0;
            Integer size3 = 0;
//            Log.d(SHETTY, "onPostExecute: result set "+result.size());


            List<LatLng> aline1 = new ArrayList<LatLng>();
            List<LatLng> aline2 = new ArrayList<LatLng>();
            List<LatLng> aline3 = new ArrayList<LatLng>();


            if (result != null) {
                int i = 0;
                Log.d(SHETTY, "onPostExecute: result size " + result.size());

                while (i < result.size()) {

                    //  for(int i=0;i<result.size();i++){
                    //result.size()
                    //int g= i-1;
                    points = new ArrayList<LatLng>();
                    // lineOptions = new PolylineOptions();
                    // if(i==1){

                    // }else{
                    List<List<HashMap<String, String>>> path1 = result.get(i);

                    for (int s = 0; s < path1.size(); s++) {
                        Log.d("pathsize1", path1.size() + "");

                        // Fetching i-th route
                        List<HashMap<String, String>> path = path1.get(s);
                        Log.d("pathsize", path.size() + "");
                        // Fetching all the points in i-th route

                        for (int j = 0; j < path.size(); j++) {
                            lineOptions1 = new PolylineOptions();
                            HashMap<String, String> point = path.get(j);
                            //  points = new ArrayList<LatLng>();
                            //                    if(j==0){    // Get distance from the list
                            //                        distance = (String)point.get("distance");
                            //                        continue;
                            //                    }else if(j==1){ // Get duration from the list
                            //                        duration = (String)point.get("duration");
                            //                        continue;
                            //                    }
                            double lat = Double.parseDouble(point.get("lat"));
                            double lng = Double.parseDouble(point.get("lng"));
                            LatLng position = new LatLng(lat, lng);
                            // Log.d("latlng", position.toString());
                            points.add(position);


                        }
                        //                lineOptions.addAll(points);
                        //                lineOptions.width(5);
                        //                lineOptions.color(Color.BLUE);
                        //                map.addPolyline(lineOptions);

                    }
                    // }
                    if (i == 0) {


//                        line1.addAll(points);
//                        mMap.addPolyline(line1);

                        size1 = points.size();

                        aline1.addAll(points);
                    } else if (i == 1) {


//                        line2.addAll(points);
//                        mMap.addPolyline(line2);

                        aline2.addAll(points);
                        size2 = points.size();
                    } else if (i == 2) {


//                        line3.addAll(points);
//                        mMap.addPolyline(line3);

                        aline3.addAll(points);
                        size3 = points.size();
                    }
                    // Adding all the points in the route to LineOptions
                    i++;


                }
                // Drawing polyline in the Google Map for the i-th route
                // map.addPolyline(lineOptions);
            }

            if (size3 != 0)
            {

                if ((size1 > size2 && size1 > size3)) {
                    if (size2 > size3) {
                        PolylineOptions line1 = new PolylineOptions().width(8).color(getActivity().getResources().getColor(R.color.grey));
                        PolylineOptions line2 = new PolylineOptions().width(8).color(getActivity().getResources().getColor(R.color.grey));
                        PolylineOptions line3 = new PolylineOptions().width(8).color(getActivity().getResources().getColor(R.color.lightblue));

                        line1.addAll(aline1);
                        line2.addAll(aline2);
                        line3.addAll(aline3);

                        mMap.addPolyline(line1);
                        mMap.addPolyline(line2);
                        mMap.addPolyline(line3);


                        Log.d(SHETTY, "onPostExecute: 3110 ");
                    } else {

                        PolylineOptions line1 = new PolylineOptions().width(8).color(getActivity().getResources().getColor(R.color.grey));
                        PolylineOptions line2 = new PolylineOptions().width(8).color(getActivity().getResources().getColor(R.color.lightblue));
                        PolylineOptions line3 = new PolylineOptions().width(8).color(getActivity().getResources().getColor(R.color.grey));

                        line1.addAll(aline1);
                        line2.addAll(aline2);
                        line3.addAll(aline3);

                        mMap.addPolyline(line1);
                        mMap.addPolyline(line3);

                        mMap.addPolyline(line2);


                        Log.d(SHETTY, "onPostExecute: 3127 ");
                    }
                } else if ((size2 > size1 && size2 > size3)) {
                    if (size1 > size3) {
                        PolylineOptions line1 = new PolylineOptions().width(8).color(getActivity().getResources().getColor(R.color.grey));
                        PolylineOptions line2 = new PolylineOptions().width(8).color(getActivity().getResources().getColor(R.color.grey));
                        PolylineOptions line3 = new PolylineOptions().width(8).color(getActivity().getResources().getColor(R.color.lightblue));

                        line1.addAll(aline1);
                        line2.addAll(aline2);
                        line3.addAll(aline3);

                        mMap.addPolyline(line1);
                        mMap.addPolyline(line2);

                        mMap.addPolyline(line3);


                        Log.d(SHETTY, "onPostExecute: 3147 ");
                    } else {

                        PolylineOptions line1 = new PolylineOptions().width(8).color(getActivity().getResources().getColor(R.color.lightblue));
                        PolylineOptions line2 = new PolylineOptions().width(8).color(getActivity().getResources().getColor(R.color.grey));
                        PolylineOptions line3 = new PolylineOptions().width(8).color(getActivity().getResources().getColor(R.color.grey));

                        line1.addAll(aline1);
                        line2.addAll(aline2);
                        line3.addAll(aline3);


                        mMap.addPolyline(line2);
                        mMap.addPolyline(line3);

                        mMap.addPolyline(line1);

                        Log.d(SHETTY, "onPostExecute: 3164 ");
                    }
                } else if ((size3 > size1 && size3 > size2)) {
                    if (size1 > size2) {
                        PolylineOptions line1 = new PolylineOptions().width(8).color(getActivity().getResources().getColor(R.color.grey));
                        PolylineOptions line2 = new PolylineOptions().width(8).color(getActivity().getResources().getColor(R.color.lightblue));
                        PolylineOptions line3 = new PolylineOptions().width(8).color(getActivity().getResources().getColor(R.color.grey));

                        line1.addAll(aline1);
                        line2.addAll(aline2);
                        line3.addAll(aline3);


                        mMap.addPolyline(line3);
                        mMap.addPolyline(line1);
                        mMap.addPolyline(line2);

                        Log.d(SHETTY, "onPostExecute: 3182 ");
                    } else {
                        PolylineOptions line1 = new PolylineOptions().width(8).color(getActivity().getResources().getColor(R.color.lightblue));
                        PolylineOptions line2 = new PolylineOptions().width(8).color(getActivity().getResources().getColor(R.color.grey));
                        PolylineOptions line3 = new PolylineOptions().width(8).color(getActivity().getResources().getColor(R.color.grey));

                        line1.addAll(aline1);
                        line2.addAll(aline2);
                        line3.addAll(aline3);

                        mMap.addPolyline(line3);
                        mMap.addPolyline(line2);

                        mMap.addPolyline(line1);

                        Log.d(SHETTY, "onPostExecute: 3196 ");
                    }
                } else {
                    System.out.println("ERROR!");
                }

        }else if(size2!=0)
            {
                if(size1>size2){

                    PolylineOptions line1 = new PolylineOptions().width(8).color(getActivity().getResources().getColor(R.color.grey));
                    PolylineOptions line2 = new PolylineOptions().width(8).color(getActivity().getResources().getColor(R.color.lightblue));


                    line1.addAll(aline1);
                    line2.addAll(aline2);

                    mMap.addPolyline(line1);
                    mMap.addPolyline(line2);

                }else
                {
                    PolylineOptions line1 = new PolylineOptions().width(8).color(getActivity().getResources().getColor(R.color.lightblue));
                    PolylineOptions line2 = new PolylineOptions().width(8).color(getActivity().getResources().getColor(R.color.grey));

                    line1.addAll(aline1);
                    line2.addAll(aline2);

                    mMap.addPolyline(line2);
                    mMap.addPolyline(line1);
                }



            }
            else if(size1!=0){
                PolylineOptions line1 = new PolylineOptions().width(8).color(getActivity().getResources().getColor(R.color.lightblue));
                line1.addAll(aline1);
                mMap.addPolyline(line1);
            }

        }




        }
```

Now for parsing JObject create DirectionsJSONParser class

```
public class DirectionsJSONParser {

    /**
     * Receives a JSONObject and returns a list of lists containing latitude and
     * longitude
     */
    public List<List<List<HashMap<String,String>>>> parse(JSONObject jObject){

        List<List<HashMap<String, String>>> routes = new ArrayList<List<HashMap<String,String>>>() ;
        List<List<List<HashMap<String,String>>>> routes1 = new ArrayList<List<List<HashMap<String,String>>>>() ;
        JSONArray jRoutes = null;
        JSONArray jLegs = null;
        JSONArray jSteps = null;

        try {

            jRoutes = jObject.getJSONArray("routes");

            /** Traversing all routes */
            for(int i=0;i<jRoutes.length();i++){
                jLegs = ( (JSONObject)jRoutes.get(i)).getJSONArray("legs");
                List path = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
                List path1 = new ArrayList<ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>>();

                // Log.d("legs",jLegs.toString());
                /** Traversing all legs */
                for(int j=0;j<jLegs.length();j++){
                    HashMap<String, String> hm1 = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    jSteps = ( (JSONObject)jLegs.get(j)).getJSONArray("steps");
                    // Log.d("steps",jSteps.toString());
                    /** Traversing all steps */
                    for(int k=0;k<jSteps.length();k++){

                        String polyline = "";
                        polyline = (String)((JSONObject)((JSONObject)jSteps.get(k)).get("polyline")).get("points");
                        List<LatLng> list = decodePoly(polyline);
                        //  Log.d("polyline",polyline.toString());
                        /** Traversing all points */

                        for(int l=0;l<list.size();l++){
                            HashMap<String, String>    hm = new HashMap<String, String>();
                            hm.put("lat", Double.toString(((LatLng)list.get(l)).latitude) );
                            hm.put("lng", Double.toString(((LatLng)list.get(l)).longitude) );

                            path.add(hm);
                            //  Log.d("lat", Double.toString(((LatLng)list.get(l)).latitude));
                            //  Log.d("lng", Double.toString(((LatLng)list.get(l)).longitude));
                        }

                    }

                    path1.add(path);

                }
                routes1.add(path1);
            }

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }catch (Exception e){
        }

        return routes1;
    }
    /**
     * Method to decode polyline points
     * Courtesy : http://jeffreysambells.com/2010/05/27/decoding-polylines-from-google-maps-direction-api-with-java
     * */
    private List<LatLng> decodePoly(String encoded) {

        List<LatLng> poly = new ArrayList<LatLng>();
        int index = 0, len = encoded.length();
        int lat = 0, lng = 0;

        while (index < len) {
            int b, shift = 0, result = 0;
            do {
                b = encoded.charAt(index++) - 63;
                result |= (b & 0x1f) << shift;
                shift += 5;
            } while (b >= 0x20);
            int dlat = ((result & 1) != 0 ? ~(result >> 1) : (result >> 1));
            lat += dlat;

            shift = 0;
            result = 0;
            do {
                b = encoded.charAt(index++) - 63;
                result |= (b & 0x1f) << shift;
                shift += 5;
            } while (b >= 0x20);
            int dlng = ((result & 1) != 0 ? ~(result >> 1) : (result >> 1));
            lng += dlng;

            LatLng p = new LatLng((((double) lat / 1E5)),
                    (((double) lng / 1E5)));
            poly.add(p);
        }

        return poly;
    }

}
```

At the end you'll have main route in blue colour and alternatives in grey. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

This should work. Tested on my application.

```
protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
    try {
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(s);
        JSONArray jsonArrayRoute = jsonObject.getJSONArray("routes");
        JSONObject jsonObjectRoute;
        int route =  jsonArrayRoute.length();
            for (int m = 0; m < route; m++) {
                jsonObjectRoute = jsonArrayRoute.getJSONObject(m);
                JSONArray jsonArrayLegs;
                jsonArrayLegs = jsonObjectRoute.getJSONArray("legs");
                JSONObject jsonObjectLegs;
                JSONArray jsonArraySteps;
                for (int b = 0; b < jsonArrayLegs.length(); b++) {
                    jsonObjectLegs = jsonArrayLegs.getJSONObject(b);
                    jsonArraySteps = jsonObjectLegs.getJSONArray("steps");
                    JSONObject jsonObjectSteps, jsonObjectLegPolyline;
                    String[] polylineArray = new String[jsonArraySteps.length()];
                    for (int i = 0; i < jsonArraySteps.length(); i++) {
                        jsonObjectSteps = jsonArraySteps.getJSONObject(i);
                        jsonObjectLegPolyline = jsonObjectSteps.getJSONObject("polyline");
                        String polygone = jsonObjectLegPolyline.getString("points");
                        polylineArray[i] = polygone;
                    }
                    int count2 = polylineArray.length;
                    for (int i = 0; i < count2; i++) {
                        mGoogleMap.addPolyline((new PolylineOptions())
                                .color(Color.BLUE)
                                .width(10)
                                .clickable(true)
                                .addAll(PolyUtil.decode(polylineArray[i])));
                    }
                }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```